# Search inside dynamic array in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to implement a code that loops inside an array that its size is set by the user that means that the size isn't constant.

for example:
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
then I want the output to be like this:

```
[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5]
[2,3],[2,4],[2,5]
[3,4],[3,5]
[4,5]
[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,2,5]
[1,3,4],[1,3,5]
and so on
[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5]
[2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Can you help me implement this code?

Answer (score 3):

From the `itertools` [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

If you don't want the empty set, it is easy to remove.

(I assume the line breaks in your example have no significance. If they do, please explain how.)

Answer (score 1):

You need [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

Example:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> A = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for i in xrange(1, len(A)+1):
...     for c in combinations(A, i):
...         print c
...         
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(4,)
(5,)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
...
...
(2, 4, 5)
(3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 5)
(1, 2, 4, 5)
(1, 3, 4, 5)
(2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```